# How to draw the input into the VCC net/bus in a circuit diagram?

Tags: schematics, diagram, symbol

I am currently drawing the circuit diagram for a device. To simplify the diagram I already using the ground symbol for all pins which are connected to ground. This makes the diagram much more readable.

But now there is a special power source (USB LiIon charger/power source) in the schema. It has various outputs, so I am currently draw all connections from the 5V output to the different components.

If I would use the symbol for VCC, it would simplify the diagram. But...

**How do I show that the 5V output of the power source provides the power for all elements connected to the VCC (symbol)?**

See this minimal example diagram:

[image: Minimal Example Diagram]

Comment: By connecting it to the net with the same name.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Technically I fully understand the concept of the named nets. It is more about the circuit diagram. Do I just draw the VCC symbol and connect the 5V pin to the VCC symbol? Does this make sense?

Comment: If its net has the same name as the other net, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just connect the source to a Vcc symbol. Make sure the name is **exactly** the same.

Here's a simple example from [this](http://www.harbaum.org/till/i2c_tiny_usb/index.shtml) webpage where the source is a USB connector and it goes to a chip and another connector.

[image]

Comment: To ensure it is the same name, I would add that copying and pasting the Vcc symbol is useful as it ensures they end up on the same net.